# The name for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, terminology, mathematical-philosophy, mathematical-writing

*What is the name (or adjective) for an assumption made for the sake of contradiction?*

To be clear, I'm in search of an expression in the form "a(n) $\underline{\quad \quad \quad \quad}$ assumption".

Edit: Why are there votes to close this question? This question at least fits the tag "mathematical-writing" and is pertinent to the writing of mathematical research papers, no doubt.

Comment: I once heard Robert Solovay refer to an assumption of this type as a "paranoid fantasy" ... but I don"t think that's an official term.

Comment: I think it is usually better to state the claim you intend to prove and then begin the proof with "Assume the contrary", so that the "contrary" does not need to be explicitly stated --- or referred to by whatever adjective you're seeking.

Comment: @Steve I agree. Still, occasionally the putative adjective lends to the flow and structure of the sentence.

Comment: a [strawman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) assumption

Comment: @Carlo Not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Aside: as an undergraduate I discovered Scott's _Group Theory_ with most of its terse proofs by contradiction beginning "Deny. Then ...", which I took as a model of a perfect proof in subsequent homework assignments.  I was rapidly disabused of this, fortunately.

Comment: In the tradition of the trials against heretics I suggest "Praesumtio diaboli".

Comment: *Marked*: "Let us assume that blah. This assumption is marked for refutation. The marked assumption implies..."

Comment: Perhaps _antithetical_?

Comment: You could call it “not” as in “Suppose not.” 

Comment: counterfactual ...

Comment: I like this question: I imagine you are asking about proof writing where you want to refer to the "contrary" assumption in the course of the proof to highlight where it is used (similar to how we would refer to the "inductive hypothesis" in a proof by induction). I think "counterfactual" that @MichaelEngelhardt suggested is good, alternatively maybe "specious"?

Comment: @ogogmad  I like "the marked assumption" and found it used a few times in logic papers.

Comment: "Counterfactual" may have the slight disadvantage that it connotes conditionals other than the material conditional; e.g., the conditionals that arise in [possible world semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Possible_world_semantics).

Comment: @WillieWong, why not just refer to "the contrary assumption", as you have done?  That seems clearer to me.  (The counterfactual assumption cannot authoritatively be literally said to be counterfactual until we're done the proof, so it had probably better not be called such during the proof.)

Comment: @LSpice I can follow your concern about "counterfactual" in a strictly logical sense, but if we, as we usually do if we care about our readers, preface our discussion with the announcement that we will show that the assumption is absurd, there should be no confusion ... or, we could say "putatively counterfactual" ...

Comment: @LSpice:I agree with your parenthetical; I was going to include that also in my comment but couldn't find a nice concise way of phrasing it, and so gave up. In regards to the "contrary assumption": I feel as if I need to specify an antecedent _everytime_ I use that phrase. This is possibly just me personally. (I think this is because "contrary" refers to the content of the assumption, rather than the method.) Perhaps I would like "contradictive assumption" better.

Comment: A good question.  We have the term "induction hypothesis".  A similar similar term for this reductio hypothesis would be useful.  I sometimes write: "Assume (for purposes of contradiction) that..."  On the other hand, sometimes you are not doing an indirect proof, you are merely proving the contrapositive.  That should be announced in a different way.

Answer (score 12):

Not ***the*** name, but ***a*** name: "contradictive assumption".

Google [knows about 80 some odd uses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contradictive+assumption%22+%22proof%22&oq=%22contradictive+assumption%22+%22proof%22) of this in a mathematical context. I like it because the word "contradictive" has a dictionary definition that is more-or-less suited for the job, and the word immediately invokes the method of proof we are using.

Answer (score 11):

Especially in the philosophy of religion, the term **reductio premise** is sometimes used.  A Google Scholar search for "reductio premise" (in quotation marks) turns up a few dozen references; one of the most highly cited is [Robust vagueness and the forced-march sorites paradox](https://web.archive.org/web/20151010180626/http://thorgan.faculty.arizona.edu/sites/thorgan.faculty.arizona.edu/files/Robust%20Vagueness%20and%20the%20Forced-March%20Sorites%20Paradox.pdf), by Terence Horgan.

However, among mathematicians, I don't think there is any standard terminology.

Comment: I was reminded today that I once used the term "reductio hypothesis" in [one of my own papers](http://timothychow.net/almost_FOCS.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Straw Man Proposal

A straw-man (or straw-dog) proposal is a brainstormed simple draft proposal intended to generate discussion of its disadvantages and to provoke the generation of new and better proposals.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man_proposal

Answer (score 1):

I liked the suggestion "the marked assumption", found in the comments. Unlike Willie Wong's suggestion the "contradictive assumption", the "marked assumption" only partially suggests the nature of the expression. This is hard to fix unless the expression is made standard.

An advantage of the "marked assumption" is that it can serve double-duty: Even in cases where the truth of the assumption is unknown, the expression is still relevant. This is particularly notable in the study of the Riemann Hypothesis where the Riemann Hypothesis is occasionally assumed and consequences derived therefrom. If the marked assumption holds, then all we have done is discover consistent structure. If the marked assumption fails, then our presumptive work can just be seen as a search for a contradiction.

Comment: In this case, why not just label your assumption "**Assumption A**" at the beginning of the proof, and refer to it as "Assumption A" throughout the course of the argument? If you are going to mark it, might as well actually mark it. (People already do this for "positive" assumptions that they need to use repeatedly in the same paper.)

Comment: @WillieWong Of course this is a valid tactic. That said, the whole point of this question is to pindown an acceptable adjective in such cases where such an adjective is desirable.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the question was to find a name for an assumption *made for the sake of contradiction*.

Comment: @NikWeaver Imagine trying to motivate a theory or definition, or even just proceeding through mathematical research. How often is the truth state of an assumption known?